# How to maintain a Set in Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb

I want my database collection to be in the below format:

```
Collection(id,<Set of String>).
```

In the mongo db official doc, I couldn't find the set datastructure. Here is a reference to the official DOC: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/

The reason to maintain a set datastructure is that if i try to add a duplicate value in the set for any key, it shouldn't get added.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what a unique index on the relevant column will enforce?

Comment: @fvu In this case, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method A: implement it as a sub-object where only the keys matter and the values are irrelevant:

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId(whatever),
    "set": {
        "Apple":true,
        "Banana":true,
        "Bob Ate My Sandwich":true,
        "Kiwi":true,
        "TheAnswerToLiveTheUniverseAndEverything":true
    }
}
```

Method B: use an array of strings to represent the set and use the [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator to add values.

Comment: Interesting. What would be the benefit of method A over method B ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux A has more overhead because of the superfluous values and isn't as index-friendly, but is more fool-proof because adding duplicates is impossible.

Comment: $addToSet is the one I'm looking for. Thanks @Philipp

Answer (score 3):

There is no dedicated *set* type in BSON.

But, MongoDB has the [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) array update operator that treats array *like* a set.